Bluetooth problem in Ubuntu 24.04
In Ubuntu 24.04 Bluetooth automatically off and on  and also does not show in the panel after  off the Bluetooth

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
